# Postgresql search in array in json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have table with columns :

`id`, `word`, `decode`

where `decode` is a json array like this:

```
[{
    "character": "三",
    "components": [
        "一",
        "二"
    ]
},
{
    "character": "大",
    "components": [
        "大"
    ]
},
{
    "character": "洋",
    "components": [
        "氵",
        "羊"
    ]
}]
```

I need search components in components. For example '二'

Comment: one more example from another 

[
  {
    "character": "俄",
    "components": [
      "亻",
      "手",
      "戈"
    ]
  },
  {
    "character": "罗",
    "components": [
      "罒",
      "夕"
    ]
  },
  {
    "character": "斯",
    "components": [
      "甘",
      "一",
      "八",
      "斤"
    ]
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `json_array_elements_text(json)` function to expands a `json` array to a set of text values, and then filter by your desired value :

```
select q.arrays
  from
  (
    select json_array_elements_text(decode) as arrays
      from tab
  ) q
 where q.arrays like '%二%';


arrays
---------------------------------------------------
{ "character": "三", "components": [ "一",  "二" ]}
```

if you exactly want to extract the sub-component which contains your character(`"二"`),then use :

```
select *
  from
  (
    select  elms -> 'components' as elm
      from  tab t,
            json_array_elements(decode) as elms
    )  q
  where elm::text like '%二%';   

elm
---------------------------------------------------
[ "一",  "二" ]
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=02b2c5f66a780ca25a35ef09c5455842)</kbd>